# Get Application specific key or secret from Graph API to use for encryption

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are exploring the Graph API to let users authenticate to our service via their MS account. However, to be able to encrypt user data properly, we need a 'secret' that we can use. Typically API's return an application specific key that is unique to the user/application that can be used for this purpose. However, I don't see anything that would be usable for that in GraphAPI.
Questions

1. Can anyone tell if getting such an application specific key is possible using the Graph API?
2. Otherwise, we will generate a secret ourselves, but want/need to store that securely in the user profile that we would be able to get after logging in. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Thanks!!

Regards,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not currently supported in Graph API. Being said that, you can file a [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for this ask so that it could be considered for future implementations.
2. Try storing the secret securely in the [Azure Key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview) and you can retrieve it from there.